# Apache (not the browser) is caching my file

Tags: apache, .htaccess, caching, centos

The browser is not caching it. It gets the response headers:

```
Accept-Ranges:bytes
Cache-Control:max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate
Connection:Keep-Alive
Content-Length:425169
Content-Type:application/javascript
Date:Thu, 09 Mar 2017 20:06:53 GMT
Expires:Wed, 11 Jan 1984 05:00:00 GMT
Keep-Alive:timeout=5, max=100
Last-Modified:Thu, 09 Mar 2017 20:06:49 GMT
Pragma:no-cache
Server:Apache/2.4.6 (CentOS) OpenSSL/1.0.1e-fips PHP/5.4.16
```

My settings in Apache:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    <Directory "/webapps/apps/devsite">
        Allow from all
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
    </Directory>
    DocumentRoot /webapps/apps/devsite
    ServerName testing.devsite.com
    SSLEngine off
</VirtualHost>
```

My .htaccess:

```
<FilesMatch "\.(html|htm|js|css)$">
FileETag None
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header unset ETag
    Header set Cache-Control "max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
    Header set Pragma "no-cache"
    Header set Expires "Wed, 11 Jan 1984 05:00:00 GMT"
</IfModule>
</FilesMatch>
```

***The following loads a new, non-cached version:***

1. on the server run: `rm -f /webapps/apps/devsite/scripts/script.js`
2. Reload in the web browser (thus getting a 404)
3. Copy the file back on to server
4. Reload in browser

***The following does loads an old, CACHED version!:***

1. On the server run: `rm -f /webapps/apps/devsite/scripts/script.js`
2. Copy the file back on to server *(NOTE: I did not reload in browser yet)*
3. Reload in browser

This shows that Apache is somehow caching it until it gets a new request and cannot find it. Why? How do i fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was it was using the kernel's SendFile which caused it to miss the file being changed. This is a Virtual Machine shared folder. Adding the following fixes it:

```
EnableSendfile off
```

(the "file" is lowercase)

More info here: https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/synced-folders/virtualbox.html

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#enablesendfile

Answer (score 0):

Apache does not permanently watch all files, only when you request a specific resource.

When you hit the 404 error, Apache loses the information about the file it has had found before.

The `last modified` timestamp does not change when you don't request a resource in the meantime.

Comment: So how do I force it to change that?

Comment: Can you please make 100% sure the browser does not cache the file (you can disable caching in Chrome in the developer console) because your Apache header look ok.

Comment: The issue was `EnableSendfile` was on and it was a shared folder in a Virtual Machine: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/350362/apache-not-browser-is-caching-my-file/350373?noredirect=1#comment620187_350373